# Essbase Hyperion Add data inside Rule Files Bulk more than 100 rows

Tags: hyperion, essbase

I already have a rule file (ex. Rule MM01), and I need to add more data rows in rule MM01 to one dimension like below.

For example I want to add more 100 rows of data in column "Replace" and column "With"

[image]

Do I have to add 100 rows one by one? Input manually? Or anything else to add bulk data into a rule file?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you just have to type them in.

If new items keep on popping-up in your source data, you might consider one of the following:

1. put your source text file into a SQL table and make your load rule read from the table (or even better, try to directly load from the tables that generated the text file)
2. (assuming you have the data load automated via MaxL) add a powershell script that does the rename before you load the data